# Thread synchronization and define atomic block using Pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I had some problems while programming C using Pthread.

There are two threads(Reader, Main) and shared resource, `fd`.
`fd` can be accessed in **blocking manner** by using `read_blocking()` and `write_blocking()`

What I intended is to write data in the Main thread whenever needed; with free-running Reader thread. I used Pthread components(Semaphore, Mutex lock, etc.) for implementing this; but encountered synchronization problem, *deadlock*.

The following is simplified code for this situation.

**Reader Thread (free-running):**

```
// Read data from `fd`
// (Separated thread other than main thread)
void ReaderThread() {
    while ( 1 ) {

        // [A]

        wait_write_complete(g_lock);

        // [!] "main thread" should NOT cut into here

        read_blocking(fd);  // [B]

    }
}
```

**Writer Function (called from main thread):**

```
// Write data to `fd`
// Called from "main thread"
void WriteData() {
    lock(g_lock);

    // At this point, the ReaderThread() shoule be @ [A] or [B]

    cancel_read();  // force terminate read_blocking()
    write_blocking(fd);

    unlock(g_lock);
}
```

**[Key Point]**

- `read_blocking()` and `write_blocking()` should **NOT** be called while the other is blocking
- `read_blocking()` can be force terminated by calling `cancel_read()`

**[Requirements]**

- No busy wait
- No `sleep()`
- `WriteData()` has higher priority than `ReaderThread()`
  (`read_blocking()` should be cancelled whenever WriteData() is called)

---

1. How to prevent `WriteData()` from interrupt between `wait_write_complete(g_lock)` and `read_blocking(fd)`(position marked **[!]**) ?

   - `wait_write_complete(g_lock)` and `read_blocking(fd)` should be atomic block
2. What type of locking mechanism is appropriate for `g_lock`?
   (Semaphore, Mutex lock, Barrier, Conditional wait, or any other?)
3. Example code will be very very helpful!! :)

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, but *assuming* you want to atomically transfer messages from one thread to another, you can do this *much, much simpler*. For example, on Linux, if your messages are no larger than 65,536 bytes, you can simply use `pipe2()` with the `O_DIRECT` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inclined to agree with @EOF that the communication pattern you describe seems excessively complex.  Taking the question as it stands, however, a **MUT**ual **EX**clusion lock is the natural synchronization mechanism for excluding one thread from taking action between two or more actions performed by a different thread.  That probably means that to achieve your aim, `wait_write_complete()` must lock `g_lock` before it returns, and `read_blocking()` must unlock it soon after function entry.

Note that you'll need to take great care to avoid simply moving the race condition into `read_blocking()`.  How you might avoid that depends on the mechanism you intend to use interrupt that function's execution.

Moreover, I suspect you'll want a shared flag indicating whether a write is pending / whether the reader may read (all access to which is protected by the same mutex), and a condition variable for suspending execution of the reader until the writer is done.  Using those, `wait_write_complete()` might then look something like this:

```
int wait_write_complete(pthread_mutex_t *g_lock) {
    int result = pthread_mutex_lock(g_lock);

    while (!result && !may_read) {
        result = pthread_cond_wait(&read_write_cv, &g_lock);
    }

    // Note: if this function returns a failure code then the state of the mutex is unknown 
    return result;
}
```

The writer thread is responsible for manipulating `may_read` appropriately, under protection of the mutex, and for signaling the condition variable when (re-)enabling reading.